# Install Navicat on Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, navicat

How do I install Navicat on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04?

I have just configured a new Ubuntu 12.04. Because I'm not so familiar with the command line, I prefer to use Ubuntu Desktop so that I can have a GUI. Now I need to install a front-end to connect with MySQL.

I prefer to use Navicat in a MAC environment, so I was hoping to install Navicat on the Ubuntu machine. I downloaded a Linux copy of Navicat for MySQL from here:

http://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-for-mysql

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to install the program after it has been downloaded. There is a navicat.exe file in the navicat folder, but that seems to be for a DOS/Windows environment.

I just can't figure out how to install Navicat onto Ubuntu Desktop 12.04. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to download [Linux version of Navicat](http://download.navicat.com/download/navicat110_mysql_en.tar.gz)

And per online [manual](http://www.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/Navicat11/en/linux/index.html)

> Installation for Download Version
>
> 1. Open or Save the gzip file.
> 2. Extract the file into anywhere you wish.
> 3. Open the unziped folder.
> 4. Double-click start_navicat to start your
>      Navicat. Please note that it would take a while for starting-up.
> 5. A Registration screen will then be popup, key in the Registration Key
>      (16 digit) and click Activate to online activate the key.

UPDATE:

if you're on 64-bit box install all 32bit libraries

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

install wine runtime environment

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Thanks @peterm but when I double-click start_navicat this asks me whether I want to `Run in Terminal` or `Run`, and neither one of these works for me.  Nothing at all happens.  `Run in Terminal` seems to flash briefly for a second, but otherwise nothing happens.  I don't know where to look to check a log to see what the problem is.

Comment: @DanielAttard See updated answer. You probably need to install 32bit libs and WINE runtime. Then double-click start_navicat and choose Run.

Comment: Thank you @peterm.  You got it working for me.  Wish I could buy you a beer.